# ThreeJS assign array materials

Tags: javascript, three.js

If I assign `framemat` to `createScene(ID,geometry,1,framemat)` it works OK, if I do `createScene( ID, geometry, 1, materials[ID] )` it doesn't work.

```
    var jsonLoader = new THREE.JSONLoader(),
    paths = [
        "obj/jgd/GALD-JGD-frame.json", 
        "obj/jgd/GALD-JGD-logo.json", 
        "obj/jgd/GALD-JGD-light.json"
    ],

    materials = [
        "framemat", 
        "logomat", 
        "lightmat"
    ],                  

    objNum = paths.length; // Cache obects.length

for ( var id = 0; id < paths.length; id++ ) {

    (function(){ // IIFE start

        jsonLoader.load( paths[id], function( geometry, materials ) { 

                createScene( id, geometry, 1, materials[id] ) 
            }
        );

    })(); // IIFE end
}
```

CreateScene fun here:

```
function createScene( id, geometry, scale, material ) {
    geometry.computeTangents();
    objects[id]= new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    objects[id].scale.x = objects[id].scale.y = objects[id].scale.z = scale;
    scene.add( objects[id] );
}
```

Comment: Why your materials are strings? Is it typing mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is ambiguous : first you define an array called `materials` then you use the second argument of the JSONLoader and also name it `materials` to catch the textures in the json file, finally you use `materials[id]` to pass the material at the mesh creation. Which one is it ? Whereas the first array is still filled with strings, the json can have an array of materials instead of only one, worse of all the rank `[id]` may not exist in this one.

So you have two solutions :

- If you want to create the materials independently, only keep the first array and add the missing function that transforms your strings to materials. Just remove the second argument of the JSONLoader.
- If you want to use the material provided in the JSON File, the array `materials` is useless and can lead to other mistakes. There are two options then :

  - if you have one material for the whole object, write it this way : `createScene(...,..., materials);`
  - if you have several materials for the object, this way : `createScene(....,....,new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials);`